# setting up storage space on HDD

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive

New to Ubuntu. Have a Win 7 system. Set up dual boot with newest version of Ubuntu. Both OSes are on partitioned 
500 MB SSD.
Data kept on 1TB HDD. 
Would like to know how to set up dedicated partition on half 
of HDD, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before reading further I'd recommend you back up any data you have on the 1TB drive, provided I understood you clearly and you need want to divide it in half for Windows data and Linux data. Resizing a partition on a drive can cause data loss. That said...

It seems you want to resize your data partition and make half of it a Linux friendly file system, e.g. ext4.

Provided you have Ubuntu Desktop install media you can run the LiveCD and use `gparted`. picture below.

[image]

It is very easy to use and you should have no problems partitioning.

If you prefer to use a Windows partitioning tool the process is the same.

- Back up any data you absolutely can't be without on the 1TB drive
- choose actions to resize the current partition on the 1TB drive to 500GB
- Make a partition with the remaining space of a file type of your choosing that is Linux friendly (Here's a brief good intro article on filetypes in case you are curious:
  https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33552/htg-explains-which-linux-file-system-should-you-choose/.)
- apply changes

Good luck!